# Contour integral over unit circle.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm completely new to complex analysis. I got this contour integral when I am reading a paper. The integral is given as follows,
$$lim_{ r \downarrow 1} \oint_{\left|\xi_{1}\right|=1} \frac{\left(1+h \xi_{1}\right)^l\left(\xi_{1}+h\right)^l}{\xi^l_{1}\left(\xi_{1}-r \xi_{2}\right)^{2}} \mathrm{~d} \xi_{1}
= \sum_{i_{1}+i_{2}+i_{3}=l - 1} \frac{\left(i_{3}+1\right) ! h^{l+i_{1}-i_{2}}}{\left(l-i_{1}\right) !\left(l-i_{2}\right) !}$$
where $l \ge 1$, $\xi_2$ and $h$ are constants.
Any tips or explanation will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cauchy's residue theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem  One of the most important things you will learn when you study complex analysis.

Comment: You did not explain what $\xi_2$ and $r$ are.

Comment: Thanks, @GEdgar, I will read it through. The r and $\xi_2$ are updated.